# What is the best way to read a string?

Tags: c, string

So I'm really confused. I have to write a program in C which is basically an address book, thus I have to get multiple strings from the user (name, ID, phone etc.)

In the beginning I tried using `scanf()` only but it messed up sometimes with the newline character `'\n'`. After some googling, I ended up using `scanf()` for getting single chars or ints (where user answers yes or no questions, or chooses an action from a menu) and `fgets()` to read the fields of the address book. However, I also had to use `fflush(stdin)` multiple times after using `scanf()` which is not recommended here as I have seen. This method worked so far as intended.

So what's the optimal way to read a string from the user? Does `fflush(stdin)` not offer portability? This is an assignment so I have to think for portability too, since I will execute my code on another computer.

Thank you in advance.

EDIT: So here is what I've got so far. Excuse some words that are written in another language (Albanian). I believe you can understand what's going on.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void regjistrim();
void kerkim();
void modifikim();
void fshirje();
void rradhitje();
void display();

#define EMRI 50
#define MBIEMRI 50
#define ID 20
#define TEL 20
#define EMAIL 25

typedef struct addressbook
{
    char emri[EMRI];
    char mbiemri[MBIEMRI];
    char id[ID];
    char tel[TEL];
    char email[EMAIL];
} addressbook;

FILE* Addressbook;

int main(void)
{
    char input[2];
    int choice;

    printf("----------------ADDRESS BOOK----------------");
    printf("\n\n\t1 - Regjistrimi i ri\n");
    printf("\n\t2 - Kerkim\n");
    printf("\n\t3 - Modifikim\n");
    printf("\n\t4 - Fshirje\n");
    printf("\n\t5 - Rradhitje\n");
    printf("\n\t6 - Afishim i address book\n");
    printf("\n\t0 - Exit\n");

    fgets(input, 2, stdin);
    sscanf(input, "%d", &choice);

    while (choice < 0 || choice > 6)
    {
        printf("\nShtypni nje numer nga 0 - 6: \n");
        fgets(input, 2, stdin);
        sscanf(input, "%d", &choice);
    }

    switch (choice)
    {
        case 1:
            regjistrim();
            break;
        case 2:
            kerkim();
            break;
        case 3:
            modifikim();
            break;
        case 4:
            fshirje();
            break;
        case 5:
            rradhitje();
            break;
        case 6:
            display();
            break;
        case 0:
            exit(0);
            break;
    }

    return 0;
}


//Regjistron nje qytetar ne addressbook
void regjistrim()
{
    char answer;

    addressbook entry;
    do
    {
        Addressbook = fopen("Addressbook.txt", "a+");

        printf("\nShtypni emrin: ");
        fgets(entry.emri, EMRI, stdin);

        printf("\nShtypni mbiemrin: ");
        fgets(entry.mbiemri, MBIEMRI, stdin);

        printf("\nShtypni ID-in: ");
        fgets(entry.id, ID, stdin);

        printf("\nShtypni nr. telefoni: ");
        fgets(entry.tel, TEL, stdin);

        printf("\nShtypni email-in: ");
        fgets(entry.email, EMAIL, stdin);

        fprintf(Addressbook, "Emri: %sMbiemri: %sID: %sNr. telefoni: %sEmail: %s\n", entry.emri, entry.mbiemri, entry.id, entry.tel,entry.email);

        fclose(Addressbook);

        printf("\nShtypni y/Y neqoftese doni te regjistroni person tjeter: ");
        fgets(answer, 1, stdin);
    }
    while(answer == 'y' || answer == 'Y');
}
```

Comment: it is not the case that `fflush(stdin)` is not recommended. It is the case that it's an **error** to flush an input stream (it results in undefined behavior). Just use `fgets()` **exclusively,** and parse the string afterwards. Don't try to combine the parsing and user input phases.

Comment: I support user3477950's view. I'd like to add that in general `scanf` is not considered a good way to read input for which structure is not guaranteed. It's pretty dangerous, and it is very hard or not possible at all, to read input safely. I am not sure if there is any *best* way. If you want to do it properly, you will end up with either some library, or reading everything as strings and parsing the buffers later.

Comment: Sorry but I can't seem to get what parsing is. Also, how would I use `fgets()` to get an int from the user?

Comment: @user3484582 Assume line is a char buffer and x is an int. `fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin); sscanf(line, "%d", &x);`

Comment: @user3484582 In this context "parsing" means figuring out what was entered. The pseudocode should be 1. Get an input line. 2. Figure out if the line contains an integer.

Comment: @Brandin I tried the `fgets()` and `sscanf()` combination but the problem persists. When I get to the first field of my struct, it automatically gets filled with empty space (though not new line).

Comment: @user3484582 You should post the code you tried along with the input. Its too hard to say just from your description. fgets and sscanf should work fine if done properly.

Comment: @Brandin I added the code to the main post. Thank you for the help so far.

Comment: @user3484582 One problem I see is that the input buffer to fgets should be large enough to hold the entire line (e.g. all characters plus a '\n' plus a '\0'). Making the input buffer only 2 characters is not recommended. I would make one buffer of like 10000 characters or something. And when you get a line, copy the relevant characters into your struct

Comment: You are right, increasing the size fixed it. I have another problem though.

On the last call,         
`printf("\nShtypni y/Y neqoftese doni te regjistroni person tjeter: ");
        fgets(answer, 1, stdin);` 
I don't get prompted to input an answer.

Comment: A buffer size of 1, maybe this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23388620/is-fgets-returning-null-with-a-short-bufffer-compliant  (hint: do not use such small buffer sizes. YOu likely want at least 3 (1 for a `char`, 1 for the `'\n'` and 1 for the `'\0'`)

Answer (score 0):

With `scanf`, you can clear the newlines, like that. Also, I have included `fgets` too.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i, N = 5;
    char buffer[N];

    printf("Enter %d characters\n", N+1);

    scanf("%5s", buffer);   /* MUST check comments below on this page for this! */

    /* Clear trailing input */
    while(getchar() != '\n')
        /* discard */ ;


    for(i = 0 ; i < 5 ; ++i)
        printf("|%c|\n", buffer[i]);

    printf("End with scanf\n\n");

    /*****************************************************/

    printf("Enter %d characters\n", N+1);

    fgets(buffer, 5, stdin);

    for(i = 0 ; i < 5 ; ++i)
        printf("|%c|\n", buffer[i]);

    printf("End with fgets\n\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Also, this code demonstrates the limit you can put to every function for the input.

[Source](http://gsamaras.wordpress.com/code/fgets-vs-scanf-overflow/)

Comment: It works great, but it seems like a sketch solution. Is it okay to use `getch()`?

Comment: @user3484582 To eat the trailing newlines? Yes.

Comment: @user3484582, if you are OK with the answer, please let me know, so that I can log off and not worrying. :)

Comment: Yeah, as I said before, it works great but now I'm trying to figure out a way to use `fgets()` only. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @user3484582 I do not know if it would be better to accept this answer (since it's ok for you) and start a new question for the program you have,

Answer (score 0):

Well "optimal" is maybe a bit subjective but I found
doing a separate function to read the number makes things
a bit easier and avoid scanf if you don't absolutely need it e.g.

```
int readNumber(int min, int max)
{
  char number[32];
  do
  {
    if ( fgets( number, sizeof(number), stdin ) != NULL )
    {
      // note that if 'number' is not a number atoi returns 0
      int n = atoi(number); 

      if ( n>= min && n <= max ) 
      { 
        return n;
      }
    }
    printf( "please enter a valid value between %d and %d\n", min, max );
  }
  while ( 1 );

  return -1; // never reached
}
```