# C - Can fgets accept a NULL parameter?

Tags: c, parameter-passing, fgets

I realize that there are some functions in the C language that have optional parameters, meaning a user can pass a NULL as a parameter value. I'm curious if this is possible using fgets().

Say I want to save an entire line in a file as a string, in other words, I want fgets() to stop when it reaches a newline character (\n), then could I do the following?

```
fgets(string, NULL, file);  //where string is simply an array of char
```

I assume this is possible since fgets() always stops when it reaches a newline character, but if it is not possible, what would be the proper procedure to save an entire line as a string when one does not know the line length?

Comment: Why would you pass `NULL` for a parameter that's not a pointer?

Comment: in practice, you can just use a long-enough buffer.

Comment: §7.1.4 Use of library functions "Each of the following statements applies unless explicitly stated otherwise in the detailed
descriptions that follow: If an argument to a function has an invalid value (such as a ... null pointer ...) the behavior is undefined." Sounds to me that passing `NULL` to `fgets` is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C does not really have optional parameters.
Though some functions have defined special values for some arguments (most common is null pointer for pointer-arguments) which mean "do the default".

You *can* use [`fgets`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgets.3.html) like [`gets`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/gets.3.html) for a specific file, by passing `INT_MAX` and thus effectivly removing the limit.
Before you consider doing so, please think about *why* C banned `gets` from the standard-library.

As an aside, `NULL` is an implementation-defined null-pointer constant, which might mean that it cannot be implicitly converted to an `int`.

Comment: I see now, I just assumed that there was perhaps a value I could pass to the second parameter so that fgets() will read all lines until a (\n) is reached. I guess the only way to do so is by passing a reasonable buffer size...

Answer (score 3):

Passing `NULL` as the size parameter to `fgets` basically passes in `0`. NULL is usually defined as

```
#define NULL 0
```

but it is meant to be used as a pointer, not an int.

I suspect the behavior of fgets() when passed a size of `0` is either undefined, or a no-op.

The documentation (on linux) states

```
fgets() reads in at most one less than size characters from  stream  and  stores  them
into  the  buffer pointed  to  by s.  Reading stops after an EOF or a newline.  If a
newline is read, it is stored into the buffer.  A terminating null byte ('\0') is stored
after the last character in the buffer.
```

How does it read in `-1` characters? Where would it store the trailing `NUL`?

This is why I lean towards undefined behavior.

In terms of reading in strings when you don't know how long they might be, there are two parts to dealing with that:

- First, make your static buffer larger than the longest expected line to minimise the chance of failing.
- Deal with `fgets` returning a full buffer (where `s[size-2] != '\n'`) by having a dynamically allocated buffer which you grow via `realloc` and use to catenate the successive returns from `fgets` until it does see a new line.

Comment: FYI: A [post on `fgets()` with size < 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23388620/is-fgets-returning-null-with-a-short-bufffer-compliant)

Comment: Ah, so the behavior is (loosely) defined, if you interpret this "no data was read"

Comment: Agree about loosely defined.  `fgets(..., 0, ...)` returns `NULL` on a number of systems and neither `feof()` nor `ferror()`, the usually cause of `NULL`, return true.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `getline` function instead. Here's the sample code from the man page

```
       char *line = NULL;
       size_t linecap = 0;
       ssize_t linelen;
       while ((linelen = getline(&line, &linecap, fp)) > 0)
               fwrite(line, linelen, 1, stdout);
```

Note that `getline` will automatically `realloc` the buffer if it's not big enough, and it's your responsibility to `free` the buffer when no longer needed.

Comment: In terms of allocating space, getline is certainly much more efficient. But from what I understand getline will not stop when it detects a (\n) character.

Comment: @Bolboa Not sure why you would think that. The whole point of `getline` is that it reads a file until it finds a `\n` character, which it puts in the buffer, just like `fgets` does.

Comment: Oh my bad, I misread the man page, it reads up to and including the (\n), whereas fgets stops at the (\n).

Comment: @Bolboa `fgets` and `getline` treat the newline exactly the same way. They stop when they find a newline, and put the newline in the buffer, followed by a NUL terminator. The only time `fgets` doesn't put a newline in the buffer is a) when a line is too long to fit, or b) if the last line of a file doesn't have a newline at the end.

Comment: Your right, I must've read a bad reference. The man page states what you just said..."Reading stops after an EOF or a newline. If a newline is read, it is stored into the buffer."