# Does feof() work when called after reading in last line?

Tags: c

I just read in a string using the following statement:

```
fgets(string, 100, file);
```

This string that was just read in was the last line. If I call `feof()` now will it return TRUE? Is it the same as calling `feof()` right at the start before reading in any lines?

Comment: No, `feof()` only returns non-zero after the first read past `EOF`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

Comment: @iharob that's when it's guaranteed to be non-zero; it may or may not be if the last character was read exactly by fgets

Comment: @user3386109 I thought of marking it as duplicate but it's not the same question. This one is asking specifically about the behavior of `feof()`.

Comment: @M.M I don't see the contradiction. If `fgets()` reads exactly up to the last character in the file, you will need to call it again to make `feof()` return a non-zero value.

Comment: *"Is it the same as calling feof() right at the start before reading in any lines?"* Even if the file size is 0 `feof` will be false just after the file is opened. The man page explains why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is **NO**.  Here is why:

If `fgets` successfully read the `'\n'` at the end of the line, the end-of-file indicator in the `FILE` structure has not been set.  Hence `feof()` will return `0`, just like it should before reading anything, even on an empty file.

`feof()` can only be used to distinguish between end-of-file and read-error conditions after an input operation failed. Similarly, `ferr()` can be used to check for read-error after an input operation failed.

Programmers usually ignore the difference between end-of-file and read-error. Hence they only rely on checking if the input operation succeeded or failed. Thus they never use `feof()`, and so should you.

The behavior is somewhat similar as that of `errno`:  `errno` is set by some library functions in case of error or failure.  It is not reset to `0` upon success.  Checking `errno` after a function call is only meaningful if the operation failed **and** if `errno` was cleared to `0` before the function call.

If you want to check if you indeed reached to the of file, you need to try and read extra input. For example you can use this function:

```
int is_at_end_of_file(FILE *f) {
    int c = getc(file);
    if (c == EOF) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        ungetc(c, file);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

But reading extra input might not be worthwhile if reading from the console: it will require for the user to type extra input that will be kept in the input stream. If reading from a pipe or a device, the side effect might be even more problematic. Alas, there is no portable way to test if a `FILE` stream is associated with an actual file.

Comment: so does this mean that the reutrn of getc will aslo be NULL if the end of file has been reached?

Comment: @Brandon: no, the return value of `getc()` at end of file (or upon read error) is `EOF`, a specific negative `int` value defined in `<stdio.h>`.

Comment: I assume you mean fgetc() right? Also does fgets() return and EOF too? Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Brandon: `getc` and `fgetc` are equivalent. `getc` can be implemented as a macro on some systems and might be more efficient.  `fgets()` returns `NULL` if it cannot read anything, otherwise it returns the pointer to the destination array.

Comment: @Brandon: can you please check this answer as accepted? You asked a separate question on the same subject, what did you miss here?

Answer (score 2):

No, don't use `feof()` to detect the end of the file. Instead check for a read failure, for example `fgets()` will return `NULL` if it attempts to read past the end of the file whereas `feof()` will return `0` until some function attempts to read past the end of the file, only after that it returns non-zero.

Comment: `fgets()` returns `NULL` in at least 2 situations: End-of-file, Input error. (maybe a [3rd](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23388620/2410359))  Using `feof()` is a **good** way to detect the end-of-file (after `fgets()` returned NULL.)

Comment: @iharob If I call fgets to check and see if the reutrn value is NULL and in reality it is not end of file, then I would have skipped a line. Is there a way to avoid this? Perhaps a way to go back to the beginning of the previous line after calling fgets to check and see if the output is NULL?

Answer (score 2):

> Does feof() work when called after reading in last line?
>
> No.

`feof()` becomes true when reading **past** the end of data.  Reading the last line may not be pass the end of data if the last line ended in `'\n'`.