# Will fgetc(fileName) pull a character if it is within an IF statment?

Tags: c, fgetc

This is the if statement I have:

```
if (fgetc(fileName) != EOF) {
}
```

I know if I run `fgetc()` when not within the `if` statement it will remove a character and I would have to do `ungetc` to return it. Will this happen when the `fgetc` is within the `if` statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it will, and since you did not store the byte that was read, you lost it.  Use this instead:

```
int c;
if ((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
    ungetc(c, fp);   /* put the byte back into the input stream */
    /* not at end of file, keep reading */
    ...
} else {
    /* at end of file: no byte was read, nothing to put back */
}
```

Also note that you should pass a `FILE*` to `fgetc`, not a filename, and `ungetc` does not `return` the character, but puts it back into the input stream so it can be read by the next `fgetc()` or `fgets()`...  You may not be able to `ungetc` more than one byte at a time before reading again from the stream.

Comment: I want the line to be put back into the input stream. So would I have to add ungetc into both the if-statment and the else?

Comment: You cannot put back a whole line into the input stream with `ungetc`, at most one byte can be put back.  No need to put anything back in the `else` part since you did not read a byte, you hit the end-of-file.

Comment: My intention for calling fgetc is to find out if it is EOF or not. If not I want it to continue reading as normal which is why I want the char to be put back into the stream. So would I need to put ungetc in if and the else part?

Comment: Also would it be a problem if I declare c as an char instead of an int? I ask because if i want to feed it back into the ungetc it would have to be char right?

Comment: `c` must be declared `int` because `fgetc()` can return all byte values **plus** `EOF`, that's too many possibilities for a `char`.  I modified the answer for your purpose.

Comment: I already gave you a detailed answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34888776/does-feof-work-when-called-after-reading-in-last-line .  What do you not understand?  Checking for end of file this way is not idiomatic in C, what is the context that makes you think it is pertinent?