# Null-termination guarantees by fgets if NULL is returned

Tags: c, stdio

While reading the C99 draft [ISO/IEC 9899:TC2 WG14/N1124](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf), I stumbled upon some statements that worries me:

**Is the string/buffer given to `fgets` also guaranteed to be null terminated if `fgets` returns `NULL`?**

§7.19.7.2 states in the description

> A
>   null character is written immediately after the last character read into the array.

But under return:

> If a read error occurs during the operation, the array contents are
>   indeterminate and a null pointer is returned.

So the last statement implies in my interpretation that this guarantee is not given in any `NULL`-returning case. 
I'm already about to correct http://en.cppreference.com, since they are using  `errno`, which `fgets` isn't obliged to set. But I'm not sure if I maybe misinterpret this.

Comment: I understand that it would not be possible to verify the buffer as null-terminated in the NULL-returning case. If there's any doubt, just don't count on having that handy trailing zero. ;-)

Comment: Since there was no character read into the array, how can a `null` character be written after it?

Comment: "*I'm already about to correct ...*" why, what?

Comment: "If a read error occurs during the operation, the array contents are indeterminate and a null pointer is returned." sounds pretty clear to me. The content of the buffer is **indeterminate** period.

Comment: Maybe I should ask this as a wiki question?! I was hoping someone could post an answer with some further references that prevent this possible misinterpretation.

Comment: @alk See http://en.cppreference.com/mwiki/index.php?title=c%2Fio%2Ffgets&diff=83790&oldid=78932

Comment: I see. However, if referring to a Standard, I'd refer to C11: http://www.iso-9899.info/n1570.html#7.21.7.2

Comment: But I see no reference to `errno`, neither in the Standard C99 version, nor in C11.

Comment: Notes about `fgets(char *s, int n, FILE *stream);` `s` may contain more than 1 null character, ones that are read and the final appended one.  A null character should not be expected  in pathological cases when `n <= 0`.  When `n==1` is also program case too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You interpret the standard correctly. In case there are errors, the function will return NULL and the contents of the buffer are not to be trusted.

This allows `fgets` to read straight into the target buffer without any double buffer in between. So upon error half-ways through the expected data, it may simply stop and return NULL.

Also note this special case (7.21.7.2):

> If end-of-file is encountered and no characters have been read into
>   the array, the contents of the array remain unchanged and a null
>   pointer is returned.

Comment: So if the buffer was null terminated before, it's stays that way, if also `feof` returned nonzero? (Sorry I've edited my question right in the moment you posted your answer)

Comment: @Superlokkus If the stream is checked with `feof` before the call to `fgets` and `fgets` encounters an error, then the contents of the buffer is indeterminate. Imagine this scenario: your buffer contains the text "hi", that is the 3 characters: `{'h','i','\0'}` followed by any random garbage. You then tell fgets to read 10 characters and overwrite the buffer, but after 5 there is an error. The buffer might at that point contain something like `{'a','b','c','d','e', <garbage> }`. The `\0` has been overwritten. Indeterminate means that the data has turned into garbage and shouldn't be used.

Comment: OK, but I guess it would be still null terminated if some additional conditions are true, like *the last character at least was already \0* or the count to fgets is >= than the times before etc. But I guess that many preconditions would just clutter up your answers and my question.

Comment: @Superlokkus Indeterminate value means that if you try to use the value for any purpose, you invoke undefined behavior. So upon error, `fgets` could as well write the string "nonsense" into the buffer and then return NULL, and it would still be strictly conforming as far as the C standard is concerned.

Comment: I thought that the special case you mentioned implies that if EOF is encountered, I could still use it, even though NULL is returned. But I overlooked the also possible scenario of feof() && ferror(). Thanks for the clarifikation.

Comment: @Superlokkus You can't know why it returned NULL unless you call `feof`. But the special case only applies when it has not read any characters yet, so that case is probably of rather mild interest.

Comment: For completeness, you may be interesting is a [3rd reason](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23388620/2410359) `fgets()` may return `NULL`.