# Is it possible to distinguish the error returned by fgets

Tags: c, fgets, eof, feof, ferror

Upon looking at the ISO C11 standard for `fgets` §7.21.7.2,  3, the return value is stated regarding the synopsis code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
char *fgets(char* restrict s, int n, FILE* restrict stream);
```

> The **fgets** function returns **s** if successful. If end-of-file is encountered and no characters have been read into the array, the contents of the array remain unchanged and a null pointer is returned. If a read error occurs during the operation, the array contents are indeterminate and a null pointer is returned.

The standard says that a null pointer is returned for either an end-of-file and no characters have been read in or a read error occurs. My question is, just from `fgets`, and the returned null pointer, is there a way to distinguish which of the two cases caused the error?

Comment: I would suspect there is a reason for `ferror()`.

Comment: The functions [`feof()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/feof.html) and
[`ferror()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/ferror.html) are designed for that.  Be aware that [`while (!feof(file))` is always wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong).

Comment: Beware, before you answer... "JUST from fgets, and the returned null pointer"

Comment: Anyway if you set to all 0 the input buffer you can see also what have partially been read.

Comment: @Frankie_C-- "If a read error occurs during the operation, the array contents are indeterminate".

Comment: @VidorVistrom that line could be a little more lax. The current conversion on ferror() and feof() is acceptable.

Comment: Tell a programmer to buy coffee while he is out, he wont ever return!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is there a way to distinguish which of the two cases caused the error?

Yes, use `feof()` and `ferror()` to distinguish. [@Nothing Nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45261601/2410359)

---

Yet it is important to use correctly.  Consider the two codes:

```
char buf[100];
fgets(s, sizeof s, stream);
if (feof(stream)) return "End-of-file occurred";
if (ferror(stream)) return "Input error occurred"; 


if (fgets(s, sizeof s, stream) == NULL) {
  if (feof(stream)) return "End-of-file occurred";
  if (ferror(stream)) return "Input error occurred"; 
  return "Should never get here";
}
```

The second properly tests the return value against `NULL`, as suggested by OP.

The first can encounter a rare problem.  The `ferror(stream)` tests  a flag. This flag may have been set by a *prior* I/O function call on `stream` so this `fgets()` is not necessarily the cause of the error.  Best to check the result of `fgets()` to see if *this* function failed.

If code is to continue using `stream` after an error detected, be sure to clear the error before continuing - like maybe to attempt a re-try.

```
if (ferror(stream)) {   
  clearerr(stream);
  return "Input error occurred");
}
```

Note that `clearerr()` clears both the error and end-of-file flags.

The same applies for `feof()`, yet most code is written to quit using `stream` once an end-of-file is true.

---

There is a 3rd *pathological* way to receive `NULL` and neither `feof()` nor `ferror()` returns `NULL` as detailed in [Is fgets() returning NULL with a short buffer compliant?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23388620/2410359).  Careful reading of the C spec has 3 "ifs", of which it is possible that not of them are true as so the spec is lacking - which implies UB.

Comment: Maybe it's not a good practice to return strings, because program may contain i18n elements, so prefer to define a enum with error codes and return enum values.

Answer (score 9):

> If the failure has been caused by end-of-file condition, additionally sets the eof indicator (see feof()) on stream. The contents of the array pointed to by str are not altered in this case.
>   If the failure has been caused by some other error, sets the error indicator (see ferror()) on stream. The contents of the array pointed to by str are indeterminate (it may not even be null-terminated).

Therefore, you would need to check for `feof()` and `ferror()` in order to determine the error.

From [this site](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets/)