# How to store multiple lines of input?

Tags: c

I am trying to read multiple lines of input from the user. My code below works fine, but my professor only allow us to use 'break' in switch statements. This is my function below:

```
void getaddress (char address [ ], int limit)
{

    int len = 0;

   while(fgets(address+len, limit, stdin))
   {
       if(strlen(address+len) == 1)
       break;

       limit = strlen(address);
       limit = limit - len;

       if(limit <= 0)
       break; 
   } 
}
```

Comment: `if (address[len] == '\n') goto done;` then after the `}` of the loop `done:;`. (checking for `'\n'` catches **Enter** alone as input for `fgets()`) If you are checking for some other condition with `strlen(address+len) == 1`, then  you can use that instead.

Comment: `while (limit > 0 && fgets(…) != NULL) { … }`, taking care not to destroy `limit` as you currently do.  Your loop body needs to calculate the new limit differently.

Comment: It appears `limit = strlen(address);` should be `len = strlen(address);` -- otherwise what `limit` was -- is changing each iteration `:)`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin you are right!!!

Comment: Combine that with the limits to your read to protect your `limit` @chux shows in his answer and you will have a solid routine.

Comment: Joana F., is the buffer size was 100, and with 3 input lines of length 40,40,40, should the last line get partially saved, lost  or what?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica the max size is 80, so what is left should be lost and maybe throw an error to retype again.

Comment: Joana F. My answer will need adjustment to handle this new requirement.  Simple look for a `fgets()` result that lacks a `'\n'` in the data just read.  See `strchr()`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica your code is working perfectly fine! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider simply reading until no room as the first test of the `while()` loop.

```
void getaddress(char address[ ], int limit) {
  int offset = 0;
  while(offset + 1 < limit && fgets(address+offset, limit - offset, stdin)) {
    offset += strlen(address + offset);
  } 
}
```

If is important that `size` in `fgets(ptr, size, stdin)` is at [least 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23388620/is-fgets-returning-null-with-a-short-buffer-compliant) to avoid problems.

Answer (score 1):

I think

```
 limit = strlen(address);//error
 len += strlen(address); // correct
```

See below

```
void getaddress (char address [ ], int limit)
{

    int len = 0;

   while(fgets(address+len, limit, stdin) && limit > 0)
   {
       switch(address[len]){
case '\0': break;
case '\n':case '\r': continue;
default:;
}

       len += strlen(address);
       limit -= len;
   } 
}
```