# how to verify fgets() read a line and handle errors

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, file-io, fgets

I am using fgets to read a file line by line

```
    char buffer[4096];

    while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), file__1) != NULL) {
           
           fprintf(file__2, "%s", buffer);
    }
```

However the [man page of fgets()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgets.3p.html) says this under the Examples section

```
           while (fgets(line, line_max + 1, fp) != NULL) {
               // Verify that a full line has been read ...
               // If not, report an error or prepare to treat the
               // next time through the loop as a read of a
               // continuation of the current line.
               ...
               // Process line ...
               ...
           }
```

My question is, upon fgets failing how could i "Verify that a full line has been read"?

Comment: See if the last character of the string is a newline.

Comment: (And don't forget the case where the file doesn't have a newline as its last character, which unfortunately happens on occasion)

Comment: If you can use it, prefer POSIX [`getline(3)`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html), which doesn't have this issue because it reallocates the line buffer if needed.

Comment: Don't forget that if there is a null byte in the middle of a line (which means the file is not actually a text file because text files don't contain null bytes — assuming a single-byte code set), then you cannot tell whether there was a newline at the end of the line because you do not know how many characters `fgets()` read.  The POSIX `getline()` function doesn't have that problem; it reports how many characters it read — and the answer should never be zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how could i "Verify that a full line has been read"?

In cases where `fgets` returns `NULL`, it means that either

- end-of-file was encountered before reading a single character (not even a newline character), or
- an error occurred on the stream.

Therefore, when `fgets` returns `NULL`, you should always assume that a full line has not been read.

However, when `fgets` does not return `NULL`, then it means that the function call to `fgets` was successfull. But this does not necessarily mean that a full line has been read. It is possible that `fgets` successfully filled the buffer, but that the line was too long to fit in the buffer. Therefore, the easiest way to determine whether a full line was read is to check whether the string returned by `fgets` contains a newline character, for example by using the function [`strchr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strchr).

Even if a newline character is not found, that does not necessarily mean that a full line has not been read. Although [POSIX defines a line to end with a newline character](https://stackoverflow.com/a/729795/12149471), it is possible that you are reading a text file which does not follow this rule. It is possible that you are reading a text file whose last line does not have a newline character, so that you encounter end-of-file without a newline character immediately beforehand. In that case, it is probably appropriate to also consider that line to be "a full line", even if you did not encounter a newline character before reaching end-of-file.

This scenario of encountering end-of-file without a newline character immediately beforehand is also possible when dealing with user input. For example, on Linux, the user can press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to enter end-of-file with the keyboard. (On Microsoft Windows, you can do the same with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, but in constrast to Linux, this will only work at the start of a line.)

For the reasons described above, in cases in which you cannot find a newline character, it is probably appropriate to check the end-of-file indicator of the stream using the function [`feof`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/feof), and to ignore the missing newline character when the end-of-file indicator of the stream is set. Only when the end-of-file indicator is not set should an error message be printed that the line is too long to fit in the buffer.

In order to read a text file line-by-line and ensure that a full line was always read, I recommend the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

FILE *fp;
char line[512], *p;

int main()
{
    //open file
    fp = fopen( "input.txt", "r" );
    if ( fp == NULL )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "Error opening file!\n" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    //read one line per loop iteration
    for (;;) //infinite loop, equivalent to while(1)
    {
        //attempt to read one line of input
        if ( fgets( line, sizeof line, fp ) == NULL )
        {
            //check for stream error
            if ( ferror(fp) )
            {
                fprintf( stderr, "Stream error!\n" );
                exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
            }

            //we must have encountered end-of-file, so break out
            //of the infinite loop without an error message
            break;
        }

        //attempt to find newline character
        p = strchr( line, '\n' );

        if ( p == NULL )
        {
            //a missing newline character should be ignored on
            //end-of-file
            if ( !feof(fp) )
            {
                fprintf( stderr, "Line too long for buffer!\n" );
                exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //remove newline character
            *p = '\0';
        }

        //a full line was read, so print it
        puts( line );
    }

    //cleanup
    fclose( fp );
}
```

Comment: Corner case: Last 511 characters of  "input.txt" lack a `'\n'`.  This code reports `"Line too long for buffer!\n"`, yet all was successfully read.  Its that "Whether the last line requires a
terminating new-line character is implementation-defined." conundrum.

Comment: @chux: In my code, I am imposing a 510 character limit (not including the newline character and the null character) on all lines. If the last line does not have a newline character, then you are right that it would be possible for me to accept 511 instead of 510 characters for that line, but this would require an additional check. I do not believe that this additional code complexity is warranted just to support an additional character in a corner case.

Answer (score 2):

This wouldn't be a failure on the part of fgets(); the control flow wouldn't go into the loop if fgets failed and returned a null pointer.

The need to handle full-line checking arises if you are reading a line with fgets and the line happens to be longer than the size passed to fgets() in argument 2. In this situation, fgets() is returning the passed buffer and is a "success".

You can check for the problem by checking whether the last character in the string is a newline. You can then either abort or handle it somehow.

So something like this would handle the check:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define LINE_MAX 5
int main() {
  char line[LINE_MAX + 1];
  while (fgets(line, LINE_MAX + 1, stdin) != NULL) {
    size_t length = strlen(line);
    if (length && line[length - 1] != '\n' && !feof(stdin)) {
      printf("line max (%d) reached\n", LINE_MAX);
      return 1;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Really boring that `fgets` returns the passed pointer on success instead of the number of characters read into it... that'd make the subsequent `strlen` unneeded :')

Comment: Note that when `length && line[length - 1] != '\n' && !feof(stdin)` is true, it does not mean this is more to the line.

Answer (score 1):

> how to verify fgets() read a line and handle errors (?)

Recall how C defines a *line* from a text file:

> A text stream is an ordered sequence of characters composed into *lines*, each line consisting of zero or more characters plus a terminating new-line character.  Whether the last line requires a
> terminating new-line character is implementation-defined.

Easy to handle many cases.  Difficult to handle all cases.

```
// Handles most
char buffer[4096];
while (fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, file__1)) {
  fprintf(file__2, "%s", buffer);
}
if (feof(file__1)) {
  printf("End-of-file detected\n");
} else if (ferror(file__1)) {
  printf("Input error detected\n");
}
```

---

What was not well handled:

- Line length was `sizeof buffer` or more.
- Input contained an embedded *null character* so `fprintf(file__2, "%s", buffer);` fails to print the entire *line*.
- When last line of file lacks a `'\n'`, some later code may have trouble with that like `*strchr(buffer, '\n') = 0;` to lop off the *potential* trailing `'\n'`.
- Reading a *text* file that does not use the local line-ending character(s) may not translate well.
- Reading a *text* file that uses wide characters does not work well with `fgets()`.
- When calling `fgets()` and `ferror()` is already true, `fgets()` may work just fine and return non-`NULL`.  Best to not test for `ferror()` unless `fgets()` returned `NULL` and then test for `feof()` first.
- Buffer sizes of [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23388620/2410359) or more than `INT_MAX`.
- Passed in pathologic size parameters of 0 or negative.
- Lines as long as 255 or more may violate an *environmental limit*.  See `BUFSIZ` details.

Additional code can handle some of these. Unfortunately `fgets()` is just not robust enough.