# Does the fgets() function always add a null terminator at the end?

Tags: c, input, null, fgets

I have a rather simple question about the `fgets` function.

As I understand, the `fgets` function tries to add a newline `'\n'` and a null terminator `'\0'` to the end.

Thus, if I give it `car` as input and write the result into an array `char line[5]`, it will contain {`'c'`, `'a'`, `'r'`, `'\n'`, `'\0'`}, is that right?

But what if I give it `carb` as input? Will the result then be {`'c'`, `'a'`, `'r'`, `'b'`, `'\0'`}?

That is, does `fgets` always force a null terminator `'\0'` into the receiving `char` array?

```c
int main(void) {
    char line[5];
    printf("Give an input. Please give max length of 3 characters so fgets can put newline and NULL inside ");
    fgets(line, 5, stdin);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### What the standard says

According to the standard (C17 draft, 7.21.7.2), `fgets`

> `char *fgets(char * restrict s, int n, FILE * restrict stream);`

reads from `stream` at most `n-1` characters (until the first `'\n'` (which is in this case also written to the target) or `EOF`) into `s[]`, appending a `'\0'`. It `return`s:

- `NULL`:

  - if `EOF` is encountered immediately (`s[]` remains unchanged)
  - if there was a *read error* (`s[]` has indeterminate contents)
- `s`: otherwise ("success")

(What happens in the case of `n <= 1` is not clear from the standard; see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76917770/2057969) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23388620/2057969).)

#### How this answers your questions

I assume that your input ends in newlines. (For input without final newlines, see the very bottom of my answer.) For both `"car\n"` and `"carb\n"` as input, `fgets(line, 5, stream)` reads `4` characters from `stream` into `line`. (It doesn't stop early because the input is at least 4 characters long, and there is no newline `'\n'` among the first 3 characters.) It then appends a null terminator `'\0'`.

The results are thus:

- `"car\n"`: `"car\n"` (null-terminated, ie: `'c'`, `'a'`, `'r'`, `'\n'`, `'\0'`)
- `"carb\n"`: `"carb"` (null-terminated, ie: `'c'`, `'a'`, `'r'`, `'b'`, `'\0'`)
  That is, the newline is cut off in this case, because it doesn't fit in. Actually, it isn't even read in by `fgets`.

Note that, while `fgets` always writes a null terminator `'\0'` at the end, it doesn't *add* a newline `'\n'`. It only *keeps* an input-final newline if it encounters one. (There can be maximally one, and it will be at the end of the resulting string (but of course before the null terminator), because `fgets` stops reading input upon encountering a newline.)

#### Testing this with code

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    FILE *fp;
    char line[5];

    fp = fopen("input.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        puts("couldn't open file");
        return 1;
    }

    fgets(line, 5, fp);
    printf("<%s>\n", line);

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

This code requires an input file `input.txt`; that way we can also easily test input not ending in newlines.

With `car\n` (with newline) we get:

```plaintext
"car
"
```

Incidentally, with `car` (no newline) we get:

```plaintext
"car"
```

With both `carb\n` (with newline) and `carb` (no newline) we get:

```plaintext
"carb"
```

This matches the expected results.