# Shouldn't fgets(s, n, stream) return an empty string instead of NULL for all n<=1?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, fgets, compiler-bug, invalid-argument

According to the standard (C17 draft, 7.21.7.2), `fgets` (¶1)

> `char *fgets(char * restrict s, int n, FILE * restrict stream);`

reads from `stream` at most `n-1` characters (until the first `'\n'` (which is in this case also written to the target) or `EOF`) into `s[]`, appending a `'\0'` (¶2). It `return`s (¶3):

- `NULL`:

  - if `EOF` is encountered immediately (`s[]` remains unchanged)
  - if there was a *read error* (`s[]` has indeterminate contents)
- `s`: otherwise ("success")

I would therefore expect that for `n <= 1`, `fgets` reads "at most" `n-1 <= 0` (that is: `0`) characters, appending a `'\0'`, and returning `s`. In any case, there is nothing being read, so the program can't read `EOF` or have any *read errors*.

However, with the following code

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char s[20];
    char *cp;
    int n;

    for (n = 2; n >= -1; --n) {
        strcpy(s, "HHHHH");
        cp = fgets(s, n, stdin);
        printf("n == %d:\n", n);
        printf("  \"%s\"\n", s);
        if (cp == NULL)
            printf("  fgets returned NULL\n");
    }

    printf("The end of main has been reached.\n");
    return 0;
}
```

and input `abcde`, I get the following output with GCC

```plaintext
n == 2:
  "a"
n == 1:
  ""
n == 0:
  "HHHHH"
  fgets returned NULL
n == -1:
  "HHHHH"
  fgets returned NULL
The end of main has been reached.
```

and the following output with MSVC

```plaintext
n == 2:
  "a"
n == 1:
  ""
n == 0:
  "HHHHH"
  fgets returned NULL
```

I am guessing that the abrupt program termination with MSVC has to do with the invocation of an "invalid parameter handler" (see Microsoft's [documentation for `fgets`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fgets-fgetws)).

For the `n == 1` case, the output is as expected. But: **Shouldn't `fgets(s, n, stream)` assign and return an empty string `""` instead of `NULL` for *all* `n <= 1` instead of just for `n == 1`?** Irrespective of what to make of the `n == -1` case, both GCC and MSVC return `NULL` for `n == 0`.

For what it's worth, the precise wording of ¶3 is:

> "[...] If end-of-file is encountered and no characters have been read into the array, the contents of the array remain unchanged and a null pointer is returned. [...]"

But if nothing is being read in the first place, how can end-of-file be "encountered" in that case?

---

**My conclusions**, after having read the comments and the content in the duplicate post:

- I am convinced now that reading "at most" `n-1` characters isn't possible for `n <= 0`. One can only read a non-negative number of characters (which I interpret to mean: a number of characters in the range [`0`, `SIZE_MAX`]).
- Therefore, in the case of `n <= 0`, the standard's text invokes what linguists in their subfield of semantics call a *[presupposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Presupposition&oldid=1156218539) failure*.

  - A *presupposition* is an assumption whose negation renders the containing statement uninterpretable. Natural language examples: "the" in a sentence presupposes contextual uniqueness; "we" in a sentence presupposes 2 or more people on whose behalf the subject is speaking; "stopped doing *X*" in a sentence presupposes that one indeed "was doing *X* for a while".
  - That is, in this case "all bets are off". However, even though the presupposition failure makes this case *literally* "undefined behavior", I would be more comfortable if we just called the standard out on this omission, because after all it doesn't outlaw an argument of `n` which is `<= 0`. (As user "chux" pointed out in a comment (paraphrased): UB comes in 2 flavors, that which is explicitly specified as UB and that about which the standard is silent; both types are common in C.)
- The case of `n == 1` looks well-formed to me (one can read "at most `0`" characters). I find the wording

  > A null character is written immediately after the last character read into the array.

  unproblematic, because not having a "last character read" is expected for the boundary condition of `0` read operations. (That is, in this case the presupposition failure can be tolerated, because it is just "one away" from there being a last character read.)

  - That said, the wording lacks clarity, and the standard should improve it.
  - To make things dependent on the stream's `EOF` flag (here `feof(stdin)`) is intriguing, but I think this goes too far in trying to assign meaning to something which is poorly worded in the standard.

That the C2x draft (I'm looking at N3096; there might be newer versions at the point of this writing) still contains the same underspecified language is a disappointment.

I believe that there are 4 potential ways we can consider handling the `n <= 0` case, given that it's not outlawed:

- setting `s[]` to `""` and `return`ing `s`
- setting `s[]` to `""` and `return`ing `NULL`
- leaving `s[]` unchanged and `return`ing `s`
- leaving `s[]` unchanged and `return`ing `NULL`

Given the existing confusion around the case, I will stay away from discussing their relative merits and consistency with other parts of the standard.

Comment: Also noted on the [cppreference page for `fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets): _"Although the standard specification is unclear in the cases where `count<=1`, common implementations do a) if `count < 1`, do nothing, report error b) if count == 1, some implementations do nothing [and] report error, [while] others read nothing, store zero in `str[0]`, [and] report success"_

Comment: @Lover of Structure,  `fgets(s, n, stream)` spec lacks clarity when `n <= 1`.  IMO, with the pathological condition of  `n <= 1`, no read is attempted, so no _null character_ is appended either given "A null character is written immediately
after the last character read into the array".

Comment: @Lover of Structure,  The return value is problematic too.  IMO, none of "The fgets function returns s if successful. If end-of-file is encountered and no characters have been read into the array, the contents of the array remain unchanged and a null pointer is returned. If a read error occurs during the operation, the members of the array have unspecified values and a null pointer is returned." applies: no success and  no read attempted.  Returning `s`, `NULL` or any valid pointer cold be seen as compliant.

Comment: @Lover of Structure IMHO, with `n == 1` and the stream end-of-file flag not set, `s` should be returned and `s[0] == 0`.  Uncertain when `n <= 0` or stream end-of-file flag set.